# How can I replicate the Bourbon Neat grid in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, grids

I am trying to set up a grid based on [Bourbon Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/) in Sketch. I tried Bootstrap grid but the grid size for Bootstrap is different compared to Neat grid.

What Layout settings could be used to reproduce Bourbon Neat grid in Sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set a layout per artboard, using these tips (considering you're using the default grid with 20px gutter) :

**Total width** : your artboard size minus 20px;

**Offset** : 10px;

**Number of columns** : 12;

**Gutter Width** : 20px;

You will have to set the Gutter Width last, so the column width can adapt.

Hope it helps.